# Disable Yammer plan (Viva Engage) using powershell and Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to work out how to disable yammer for some users with powershell. I have made a script before which worked fine but this no longer works due to Microsoft deprecating it, so now I must use Microsoft Graph. I have managed to add licences with the graph api

```
 Set-MgUserLicense -UserID "$o365name" -AddLicenses @{SkuId = "MySkuID"} -RemoveLicenses @()
```

but I cannot seem to figure out how to remove options (yammer) with the graph api

here is what I used to do:

```
$LO = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId STANDARDWOFFPACK_STUDENT -DisabledPlans YAMMER_EDU

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $o365name -LicenseOptions $LO

$LO = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId STANDARDWOFFPACK_IW_STUDENT -DisabledPlans YAMMER_EDU

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $o365name -LicenseOptions $LO
```

Answer (score 0):

So I need to run this:

```
## Get the new service plans that are going to be disabled
$e5Sku = Get-MgSubscribedSku -All | Where SkuPartNumber -eq 'STANDARDWOFFPACK_IW_STUDENT'
$newDisabledPlans = $e5Sku.ServicePlans | `
Where ServicePlanName -in ("YAMMER_EDU") | `
Select -ExpandProperty ServicePlanIdenter code here

## Merge the new plans that are to be disabled with the user's current state of disabled plans
$disabledPlans = ($userDisabledPlans + $newDisabledPlans) | Select -Unique
$addLicenses = @(
 @{
      SkuId = $e5Sku.SkuId
      DisabledPlans = $disabledPlans               
}
)
## Update user's license
Set-MgUserLicense -UserId "USER EMAIL ADDRESS" -AddLicenses
 $addLicenses -RemoveLicenses @()
```

I had to also run the same code for:

```
$e5Sku = Get-MgSubscribedSku -All | Where SkuPartNumber -eq 'STANDARDWOFFPACK_STUDENT'
```

Because users had both A1 and Plus packs

**NOTE:** The Service Plan name might change soon as Yammer is now called 'Viva Engage' however MS haven't appeared to update the licence name just yet.

See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/disable-access-to-services-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide